# Date format returned as mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM

Tags: sql, date, datetime, sql-server-2012

I am brand new to sql my company just kinda threw me head long into this and said do it. So any help is greatly appreciated. I am trying to get a date to come out in the format of mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM so for example a date of 09/26/2014 11:04:54 AM. I have tried using the code:

```
Select Convert(nvarchar,EntryDate,101)
From DB1
```

However that returns just 09/26/2014.
I also tried

```
Select Convert(nvarchar,EntryDate,100)
From DB1
```

but this returns Sep 26 2014 11:04AM

Not sure where to go from here. Again thanks for the help. BTW I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Looking at the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) it's not clear there's a style which covers what you want. I would encourage you to do formatting at the client though - do you really need to do it in the database?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you're on SQL 2012 the format function should work:

```
declare @date datetime = '2014-09-26 11:04:54'
select FORMAT(@date,'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:s tt')
```

result: `09/26/2014 11:04:54 AM`

In your case it would be:

```
Select FORMAT(EntryDate,'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:s tt')
From DB1
```

Comment: Not sure why but I was getting the error that Format was a not recognized function. I even double checked to make sure I was in SSMS 2012 as I have both 2012 and 2008 on the computer

Comment: The Server is probably not 2012 just my front end program that makes sense. Good thinking.

Comment: select FORMAT(getdate(),'dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm:s tt') this command work in SQL 2012 server perfectly. Its also work in SQL 2008.

Comment: Format is the best option as it allows us to write any culture we want

Comment: Thank you for telling us about this! You changed my life!  No more impossible-to-understand 101, 132, etc  in my views!!!

Comment: FORMAT() is not valid in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 14):

```
DECLARE @Date_Value DATETIME = GETDATE();


SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Date_Value, 101) + ' ' 
       + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), @Date_Value, 22), 11))


RESULT: 09/26/2014 5:25:53 PM
```

### Your Query

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), EntryDate, 101) + ' ' 
       + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), EntryDate, 22), 11))
From DB1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    > select convert(varchar(20),GETDATE(),1)+' '+convert(varchar(20),convert(time,getdate()),100)
    > select convert(varchar(20),GETDATE(),103)+' '+convert(varchar(20),convert(time,getdate()),100)
    > select convert(varchar(20),GETDATE(),103)+' '+convert(varchar(20),convert(time,getdate()),22)


    > Result (1) :-  10/15/2018 11:22AM (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM)
    > Result (2):-  15/10/2018 11:22AM (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM)
    > Result (3):-  15/10/2018 11:22:35 AM (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM)
```

Comment: i have two query 1st query return mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM and second one is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM

Answer (score 2):

You can use FORMAT function in sql

```
SELECT FORMAT(@date,'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:s tt')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this to convert a date in the format you ask for DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m %d %Y %h:%i %p'). Where date is the date you want converted.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

USING two formats and concatenating them with REPLACE and SUBSTRING functions.

```
   select CONVERT(nvarchar(128), dbo.GetDateTime(@input), 101) + 
           REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(128), 
           dbo.GetDateTime(@input), 109), 12 , 128),':000', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining two formats:

```
select convert(char(11),getdate(),103) 
      + stuff(right(convert(char(31),getdate(),130),14),9,4,' ')
```

yields:

```
26/09/2014 12:29:09 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

As yet another way to solve the same problem this works.

```
Select Convert(char(10), getdate(),101) + Right(Convert(VarChar(20),getdate(),100),8)
```